# Transparent fork-server on linux

Tags: linux, fork

Suppose I have application `A` that takes some time to load (opens a couple of libraries). `A` processes stdin into some stdout.

I want to serve `A` on a network over a socket (instead of stdin and stdout).

The simplest way of doing that efficiently that I can think of is by hacking at the code and adding a forking server loop, replacing stdin and stdout with socket input and output.

The performance improvement compared to having an independent server application that spawns `A` (fork+exec) on each connection comes at a cost however. The latter is much easier to write and I don't need to have access to the source code of `A` or know the language it's written in.

I want my cake and eat it too. Is there a mechanism that would extract that forking loop?

What I want is something like `fast_spawnp("A", "/tmp/A.pid", stdin_fd, stdout_fd, stderr_fd)` (start process `A` unless it's already running, clone `A` from outside and make sure the standard streams of the child point to the argument-supplied file descriptors).

Comment: The simplest way of doing that would be using _inetd_, because it's a well known and well reviewed program. Do you really have a bottleneck in program startup of some milliseconds while having programs running across networks?

Comment: Or perhaps even simpler, use [netcat relays](http://www.michaelboman.org/books/penetration-testing-notes/netcat).

Comment: Or perhaps `socat`. `socat` can redirect everything you can imagine of to everything you can imagine of (and more). I used it for example for an ancient server which reads from a serial input `rs232` and I needed it to talk over `tcp`. Since a terminal is a serial input as well, go for it.

Comment: Btw, I suggest to ask the question on serverfault oder superuser. It is not really off-topic here since you are wondering if there is a coding solution, but you might get better answers there.

Comment: The question is not about redirecting though. What I want is preload the handler process up until it starts blocking on stdin (have it load all of its dependencies), and then clone that process image >>from outside<< and rewire standard streams on each connection. I don't see how `netcat` solves the problem.

Comment: If you don't want to get into OS-specific internals, i.e. keeping it maintainable by others and standards compliant, just stay with fork/exec. You would have to change the process image from outside to exchange file descriptors, which is QUITE OS-specific. If there is a real need to get close to your desires, you could use UNIX domain sockets to exchange file descriptors.

Comment: Passing fds via UNIXsockets is really IMO just a microoptimization  compared to the speedup you can get by not having to spawn big processes on each request. It's also needless if you spawn, because then you already have all the fds of your parent process by default. Also there's nothing in this question that says I don't want to get into OS-specific internals. I'd say the linux-tag in fact suggests otherwise. :)

Comment: The process doesn't have to be spawned again if you use UNIX domain sockets. You have one process listening to the network that sends sockets/file descriptors through the UNIX domain socket to "process A". This one in turn has to listen to the UNIX domain socket and call fork/exec. It's really a very little gain compared to listening to the network in process A in the first place. Could come in handy for privilege separation though.

Comment: Also keep in mind that process A is not guaranteed to be in a constant state just because it's blocking on stdin (also exchanging a file descriptor while the process is blocking on it is "challenging", to say the least). There are possibly signal handlers executing, which means that an outside clone could lead to undefined behaviours. It's easier to keep everything inside one program.